# What does the abbreviation "SA" in my score mean?

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music

In have no idea what the abbreviation stands for nor its interpretation for the singer.  The positioning of this abbreviation sits atop the staff sometimes.  I could only find the (multiple) abbreviations for "SA" (meaning) but not how to sing this.

Comment: Give more context.

Comment: We can't do any more than guess until you post a scan of the page.  I imagine if this was a choral score you'd have said so?

Answer (score 6):

In a four-part chorale texture, there are four voices singing: soprano (the highest), alto, tenor, and bass (the lowest). We commonly call this an SATB texture, although there are other arrangements.

The "SA" stands for "Soprano and Alto," and it indicates which voices are shown on a given staff.

In the example below, "SA" next to the treble clef indicates that the voices in that staff are the soprano and alto; the "TB" next to the bass clef indicates tenor and bass.

[image]

Comment: Certainly not denigrating the answer, but wouldn't it be apparent from the pitches written, and their placing on the stave/s? And - is that tune in G Dorian?  Just curious! +1.

Comment: Whether this applies to the OP's under-specified question is anyone's guess. +1 for giving an answer of general applicability.

Comment: @Tim, I'd agree the SA and TB are not *necessary*, but do provide an extra courtesy. I would think this is mostly for untrained singers in choruses, who barely read music. The top clef *could* be misinterpreted as TT.  Some people do not always notice there is a little 8 at the bottom of the clef sign to signify it is for tenors.

Comment: A four-part chorale style does not have to be SATB. It could also be TTBB or SSAA.

Comment: @HeatherS. - is it normal for tenor parts to be written in treble clef? The standard SATB is both, so why provide the extra courtesy which, for this OP, didn't mean anything anyway! And - I think the range would be a good giveaway.

Comment: @Tim, if the tenor part is written on it's own staff, it has a treble clef with a little 8 at the bottom to indicate that the pitches sound one octave lower than written. If a tenor part is written on the same staff as the bass part, the bass clef is used.  This is pretty standard.  I accompany church choirs and community choirs, including a men's choir.

Comment: @HeatherS. - I'm sure that's true - you should know. But it does beg the question why bother having two ways to do the same job. Maybe rather like if you're a trombonist, you need to be conversant in several different ways of reading.

Comment: @Tim, I don't know what you mean by having two ways to do the same job. The treble clef works better than bass clef for tenor range, as the bass clef works better for bass range, but if the two voices must share a staff, it is preferable to use bass clef for both. Cellists, violists, and bassists also must read multiple clefs and pianists have to be ready to read either clef to play with either hand.

Comment: @HeatherS. - point taken about some instruments - but bass? I meant using a clef that is best suited - like alto clef for example, although I understand using treble for tenors, as a guitarist, I read that as it's all we have! Just one of the joys of being a tenor, I suppose - needing to read either clef.

Comment: Again, perhaps I am misunderstanding. The clefs normally used for the voices and instruments cover the majority of pitches that are needed without using too many ledger lines. If you are asking about the bass (instrument), my son plays double bass. He must read treble clef when he plays in the highest part of the range (occasionally tenor clef is used.)